# Arduino/coding noobing having issues adding something to an already working sketch

Tags: arduino

Being a Arduino and coding noob, I've been running into brick walls testing ways to make this work.

I would like LED2 to blink while LED1 is on. I'm not exactly sure which control to use and where to put it.

```
int b1IN = 10;
int LED1 = 11;
int b2IN = 4;
int LED2 = 3;
boolean lastButton = LOW;
boolean ledOn = false;
boolean currentButton = LOW;
void setup() {

  pinMode(b1IN, INPUT);
  pinMode(LED1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(b2IN, INPUT);
  pinMode(LED2, OUTPUT);

}

  boolean debounce(boolean last){

    boolean current = digitalRead(b2IN);
    if (last != current){

      delay (15);
      current = digitalRead(b2IN);
    }

    return current;
  }



void loop() {

  currentButton = debounce(lastButton);

  if (digitalRead(b1IN) == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);
    delay(20000);
    digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
  }

  if (lastButton == LOW && currentButton == HIGH) {

    ledOn = !ledOn;

  }

    lastButton = currentButton;
    digitalWrite(LED2, ledOn);
}
```

Comment: Please better describe the actual problem or behavior you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to push button 1 making LED1 illuminate for 20s and cause LED2 to blink while LED1 is illuminated. I've tried using a do in the if that controls LED1, I've tried a do/while in between the two ifs. I've also tried an if in the same spot.

Comment: I've also tried an if in the same spot. I have gotten zero results, no change in how the sketch works and no errors.